# How to access multiple kusto let statement results in a consecutive query?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

I'd like to query the input value for the `bin()` function prior to the execution, in which the three dots (...) represent a integer variable:

```
let bin_size = 
T 
| project X, Y
| summarize y_bin_size=(max(Y) - min(Y)) / ..., x_bin_size=(max(X) - min(X)) / ...;
let result = 
T
| project X, Y
| summarize Count=count() by bin(X, bin_size.x_bin_size), bin(Y, bin_size.y_bin_size);
result
```

In ADX the bin_size is shown by hovering over the variable, as shown in the image:

[image]

Therefore, I suppose, I could access the variables `y_bin_size` and `x_bin_size` for my final query.

How can I access the inner results of the first let query?
Can I combine this in one query?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try something like this:

1. in the first part of the query: calculate and store the bin sizes in a scalar property bag of type `dynamic`.
2. access the properties (`x` and `y`) from the bag in #1 in the other part of your query.

```
let bin_sizes = toscalar(
    T
    | summarize bag_pack("y", (max(Y) - min(Y)) / 5,
                         "x", (max(X) - min(X)) / 6)
)
;
let result = 
    T
    | summarize Count=count() by
          bin(X, todouble(bin_sizes.x)),
          bin(Y, todouble(bin_sizes.y))
;
result
``
```

Comment: Really nice and pretty fast response. Thanks a lot.